# Customize display text in a jquery plugin - jqpagination

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, jqpagination

I am using the famous `jqPagination` for paginating my `divs`. As mentioned in the project page [here](http://beneverard.github.com/jqPagination#demo).

I was able to successfully test the plugin. It works.

But, the question is this: It displays `"Page 1 of 5"` which i want to customize to something just like, `"1 of 5"` (*eliminating the word Page*).

Any ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built into jqPagination, instantiate the plugin like so:

```
$('.pagination').jqPagination({
    max_page: 40,
    page_string: '{current_page} of {max_page}',
    paged: function(page) {}
});
```

The `page_string` option can be any string you like, with `{current_page}` and `{max_page}` being placeholders for jqPagination.